# click event on different child selector with same selector

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have a click event on different child selector with the same selector.
When I try, only the last trigger.

Thank you.

```
$('#datableAddress').off().on('click', '#edit', function () {})

$('#datableAddress').off().on('click', '#delete', function () {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.off()` before your `.on()` to add multiple event handlers without removing the old ones :

```
$('#datableAddress').on('click', '#edit', function () {})

$('#datableAddress').on('click', '#delete', function () {})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easiest to do by changing the selector so that it will work for both, like this:

```
$('#datableAddress').on('click', '#edit, #delete', function () {})
```

If there is no other need for the off, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this

**First Option**

document `.on` click event

```
$(document).on('click', '#datableAddress #edit', function () {
    alert($(this).text())
});

$(document).on('click', '#datableAddress #delete', function () {
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

---

**Second Option**

`.on` click event directly on the selector

```
$('#datableAddress').on('click', '#edit, #delete', function () {
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

---

**Third Option**

`click` on the element

```
$('#datableAddress #edit, #datableAddress #delete').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text())
});
```

---

**Fourth Option**

keeping `.off` event to unbind the selector and add `.on` event to the element again to bind it

```
$('#datableAddress #edit').off('click').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).text())
});

$('#datableAddress #delete').off('click').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).text())
});
```